# CSS: why line-height disturbs the width?

Tags: css

How does the line-height property in CSS works? If i set the `line-height` equal or less than the font size, it creates the problem with layout width. [Please check this jsFiddle to see the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/szHzS/)

I'm using font-size 14px, and line height 14px. If you change the `line-height` to 15px or more, the problem will be solved. Shouldn't the `line-height` only change the height, not disturb the width?

Please see the image below, as you see the `#wrap` has width of 300px, now because of line height the two div's of width 150px are not fitting into it.
I have checked with firefox and chrome, latest versions.

[image]

Comment: I only see a difference in line-height when I change it. Width doesn't change. Which browser do you have?

Comment: does this problem occur in all browsers you test?

Comment: I just edited and added screenshot.

Comment: Line-height is [much more complicated](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-line-height/) than it seems. It looks like the problem on my browser (Firefox 6.0.2) is that the presence of the scrollbar pushes the second floated div below the first due to insufficient width. This could just be a result of how the browser renders this example.

Comment: @yeah exactly, and in firefox the `<div>`s will be side by side if you increase `line-height` to 15px.

Comment: In Chrome too, Roman. But without changing the width of the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with line height... not directly atleast. The two boxes will remain 150px wide regardless of whether you specify a line height or not. The `overflow: auto` causes a vertical scroll bar to appear (for reasons unknown to me) which reduces the available width of your container from 300px to ~280px hence the two colored boxes cannot appear side by side anymore. If you remove `overflow: auto` the [result will appear as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/szHzS/14/).

## Edit

Revised [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/szHzS/15/). To counter the vertical scrollbar, I added 1px padding on the container which seemed to counter the problem. For larger font sizes, use a padding of 2px.

Comment: sure, remove line height and keep overflow. or increase line-height to 15px in ff or 18px in chrome, and keep overflow, it wont have any problem. So the problem is caused by the line-height, not the overflow.

Comment: No. It *is* caused by overflow. In the demo above I've used line height of 14px and the taller content renders on 7 lines. 7x14px = 98px. If you set overflow to hidden, #wrap will stretch to 98px and no scrollbar is added. If you set overflow to auto, the browser (incorrectly) adds the vertical scrollbar which screws up the layout. If you can live without `scrollbar: auto` the there is no problem. If `scrollbar: auto` is necessary, I have a solution. Just let me know.

Comment: I have to agree with @Salman, there is no problem with line-height. You can also solve this issue by adding clear right to #left and #right columns

Answer (score 2):

Line height is an inherited property but its inheritance works in a complicated way as compared to other inherited properties.

There is an excellent slideshow to Illustrate how line-height works depending on the units you specify the line height.

http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height.

Slide 28 onwards explains your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, if I increase the line height to 18px, the divs will be side by side, but the width doesn't change. Apparently this has something to do with the calculation of the height of #wrap. The browser cannot decide wether to show the scrollbar in #wrap or not. But since #wrap  is exactly 300 wide, and thus can hold the two divs side by side only when the scrollbar isn't displayed, you'll have to force to hide it. Change #wrap overflow to `hidden`, or remove this property altogether.